# Click twice for two onClick events

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to have one onClick event, on the first click it uses one function and the second click it uses another?

e.g.

```
<p id="demo" onclick="goRed(), goBlue()">Click me to change my text color.</p>

<script>
    function goRed() {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
    }
    function goBlue() {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "blue";
    }
</script>
```

Can I make it so the onClick function uses goRed() first, then goBlue() after a second click?
Thanks

Comment: store a boolean or a counter, then test its value on click and increment/change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use one function, but toggle between the different colours in that function:

```js
function toggleColor() {
  var el = document.getElementById("demo");
  
  if (!el.style.color || el.style.color == "blue")
    el.style.color = "red";
  
  else
    el.style.color = "blue";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo" onclick="toggleColor()">Click me to change my text color.</p>
```

Here we set the `color` to "red" if the element's `color` is currently "blue" or hasn't yet been set. Otherwise we set it to "blue".

Comment: Why do you set the event handler inline and not via addEventListener?

Comment: @Mouser because this is not a question about *how should I rewrite my inline `onclick` function*. I've answered the question asked, but decided not to go above and beyond the call of duty as the question you're wanting me to answer has been answered countless times here.

Comment: For some cases I agree, but if you do go about rewriting a complete function, then a small addition could be to educate about more standard approaches or at least hint on them. But I think that's my background as a teacher speaking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="demo" onclick="goRed()"> Click me to change my text color.</p>

<script>
   function goRed() {
       document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
       this.onclick = goBlue;
   }
   function goBlue() {
       document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "blue";
       this.onclick = goRed;
   }
</script>
```

This will do it. But it's not nice. So we can update that:

First let us use an event handler. They are the standard. Try to avoid inline event handlers.

```js
    document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", goRed, false);

    function goRed(e) {
        this.style.color = "red";
        //this refers to the element.
        this.removeEventListener("click", goRed, false); //remove the event listener
        this.addEventListener("click", goBlue, false); //add the blue one.
    }
    function goBlue(e) {
        this.style.color = "blue";
        this.removeEventListener("click", goBlue, false); //remove the event listener
        this.addEventListener("click", goRed, false); //add the Red one.
    }
```

```html
<p id="demo" > Click me to change my text color.</p>
```

I've chosen not to implement one function for the color changing, since I wanted to make this answer more general. This is the correct way to change the event handler of an element within a function to another function. The color changing is just an example. One could imagine other cases where the function reference of a link or button needs to be changed after a function is executed.

Comment: Nice a downvote without proper explanation and on correct code that answers to the question.

Answer (score 0):

also you can do it via `switch`

```
function toggleColour() {
 var color=document.getElementById("demo").style.color;
 switch(color){
 case "red":
      color.style.color = "blue";
      break;
 case "blue":
      color.style.color = "red";
      break;
 default :
   console.log("the color are not posible to change");
   break;
  }
}
```

add this to your HTML file

```
<p id="demo" onclick="toggleColour()">Click me to change my text color.</p>
```